# VS2015 CUDA project compiles and runs but Intellisense cannot find includes

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, cuda, intellisense

I am running VS2015 community and working with a mixed OpenCV/CUDA code. The project runs as it should but Intellisense squiggles under the include headers. When I right click, it gives this error.
[image]

Things I have already tried:

1. Restarting VS (at least a dozen times).
2. Deleting the `.vs` folder in the project folder.
3. Deleting the `*.vc.db` in the project folder.
4. Check the `Additional Include Directories`
5. Remove the `Additional Include Directories` > Fail to compile > Add them back > successfully compiles.
6. Make sure I am on `x64` and `Debug`. I am using `OpenCV 3.2 x64`.

Other stackoverflow questions I have already referred with no success

1. [why visual studio editor can not find a header file, when compiler can find it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823228/why-visual-studio-editor-can-not-find-a-header-file-when-compiler-can-find-it)
2. [Visual Studio 2008 oddity with C++ and header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499523/visual-studio-2008-oddity-with-c-and-header-files)
3. [Visual Studio can't 'see' my included header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490015/visual-studio-cant-see-my-included-header-files)
4. [How to rebuild VS2010 IDE Intellisense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830397/how-to-rebuild-vs2010-ide-intellisense)
5. [Visual Studio 2015: Intellisense errors but solution compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943634/visual-studio-2015-intellisense-errors-but-solution-compiles)
6. ['Additional include directories' in visual studio 2010 doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829163/additional-include-directories-in-visual-studio-2010-doesnt-work)
7. [Visual Studio 2010 intellisense not recognising additional include directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682325/visual-studio-2010-intellisense-not-recognising-additional-include-directory)
8. [Visual Studio 2012 - Intellisense sometimes disappearing / broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375961/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-sometimes-disappearing-broken)
9. [Visual Studio C# IntelliSense not automatically displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420303/visual-studio-c-sharp-intellisense-not-automatically-displaying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had to do something with the CUDA build settings in the project. I fixed the problem by moving `$(OPENCV_DIR)\include` from `Additional Include Directories` to simply `Include Directories`.
[image: Remove from here]
[image: Add here]

Comment: The thing is that if you working with a pure OpenCV project and are just linking against the library (and not writing any CUDA code yourself), you don't even need to set up a CUDA project in VS.

Comment: Yes, if I am not writing any CUDA code, I dont need to setup CUDA project. I dont understand your point.

Comment: So why are you using a CUDA project to compile something that appears to only use  OpenCV?

Comment: I am using OpenCV to read and write images from the disk. CUDA is for image manipulations.

Comment: At no point, anywhere, did you mention that in either your question or answer

Comment: I thought it was irrelevant.

Comment: So how could someone else possibly have either given you this answer (or understand why you tagged the question as  a CUDA question)?

Comment: I tagged CUDA, after I had answered the question. I expected it to be a Visual Studio cache related error.